# Dynamically extract All CSS Selectors of a Webpage(Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, selenium

I need a java program or a javascript program which will dynamically fetch all the css Selectors of the webelements in a Webpage(from DOM)...i HAVE used the following code for gmail login page but it is not working.

public String javascriptfunction(WebDriver driver)
    {

```
    String javaScript = "jQuery.fn.getPath = function ()" 
              +"{"

    + "if (this.length != 1)" 
    + "throw 'Requires one element.';"

    + "var path,node = this;"
    + "while (node.length) {"
    + "var realNode = node[0], name = realNode.localName;"
    + "if (!name) break;"
    + "name = name.toLowerCase();"
    + "if (realNode.id) {"                    // As soon as an id is found, there's no need to specify more.
    +  "return name + '#' + realNode.id + (path ? '>' + path : '');"
    + "}"
    + "else if (realNode.className) {"
    + "name += '.' + realNode.className.split(//s+/).join('.');"
    +   "}"
    + " var parent = node.parent(), siblings = parent.children(name);"
    +   "if (siblings.length > 1) name += ':eq(' + siblings.index(node) + ')';"
    + "path = name + (path ? '>' + path : '');"
    + "node = parent;"
    + "}"
    + "return path;"
    + "};";

    System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript));
```

return  (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript);

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Run the same jQuery using Chrome's Developer tools, see what response you get back. What does "not working" mean? Errors? Fail silently? What are you running this against (browser)?

Comment: Actually my requirement is like fetching all the css selectors in a webpage using Selenium Webdriver(testng or junit)..It's a tuff task but could you give me some links for the same..

Comment: I am in need to populate all the css selectors of the webpage dynamically to an excel sheet(programmatically) without getting the help of plugins like firebug,firepath etc